# Access to the path is denied in C# application which is being used by another application

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I am trying to read some log files for one application. While I am trying to read those files, they are being used by some other application.

That is why I am using the following line of code to read those files -

```
FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(logFileStream);

String line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 ....
}
```

Unfortunately, this code is also not working. Any idea why this is not working even after setting **FileAccess to Read** and **FileShare to ReadWrite**? I even it by setting it to  **FileShare.Read**.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Probably because the OTHER process hasn't opened the files in shared mode. (Also note that your code would be better written as `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))`)

Comment: As Mathew has said.. Without specifying the FileShare parameter, if you open a file, it will be locked exclusively by the opening application, and you will receive an exception as is happening. So basically if you can't change how the other app opens the file try something more friendly like File.Open(<file-path>, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read) which basically says If you permit (read, not throw exception), I would like to read the file, though I will not try to own it and I know that you may modify it.

Comment: Also, makesure use use `using` to dispose the object afterwards.